# Need help modifying li item in bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to add some custom css to modify a bootstrap navbar. I have an example below:

http://jsfiddle.net/AfjL5/

The part I need help with is this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="red"><a href="#">EXIT</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to modify the <li> item in the navbar (The red exit button) so that it extends to the bottom of the navbar. I've tried setting the height to 100%, but that doesn't do anything. I've also tried inspect element in chrome and modified everything I could think of with no success.

Note, you may need to resize the jsfiddle window because if it's too small the responsive design moves the <li> to a new row.
Also, the idea is that no matter how many rows the H1 takes up (which modifies the size of the navbar), the LI always extends to the bottom.

I appreciate all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this

```
ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right {
    margin-right: auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}

.red {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    height:100%;
}
```

You might adjust `top` and `bottom` to make it responsive. Otherwise normally it'll work fine.

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AfjL5/2/)